# how to install apk application from my pc to my mobile android

Tags: android

I have 2 questions:

First, I need to  to install apk application from my pc to my mobile android?

Second, how I run my code in the mobile directly? I install usb driver but my pc can't detect the usb of my mobile

Comment: Your first question is answered here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5566/how-can-i-install-an-app-given-only-its-apk-file. But you'll probably have to figure out that second question, first. Make sure your phone has Unknown Sources enabled.

Comment: Go to Settings | Applications | Unknown Sources.

Answer (score 12):

To install an APK on your mobile, you can either:

1. Use [ADB](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) from the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), and do the following command:
       `adb install filename.apk`.
   Note, you'll need to [enable USB debugging](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/mobile/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-android-phone/) for this to work.
2. Transfer the file to your device, then open it with a file manager, such as [Linda File Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lindaandny.lindamanager&feature=search_result).

Note, that you'll have to enable installing packages from [Unknown Sources](http://android-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/02/installing-non-market-apps-on-android.html) in your Applications settings.

As for getting USB to work, I suggest consulting the [Android StackExchange](http://android.stackexchange.com) for advice.

Answer (score 1):

1) Put the apk on your SDKCard and install file browsers like "Estrongs File Explorer", "Easy Installer", etc...

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&feature=search_result
https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.infolife.installer&feature=search_result

2) Go to your mobile settings - applications- debuging - and thick "USB debugging"
[image]

Comment: 2) I check USB debugging but mon pc still not detect my phone. T didn't receive any notification to inform me that my phone is detected.

Comment: You can try the command "adb devices" that will tell you if a device is connected.
If you cannot detect a device there are only 1 explanation, I think: you certainly need to re-install your driver. Some devices (like Archos, Acer, need a special adb file or some tweaks) maybe you should tell us what device you have.

Comment: I think the model of my computer :D Samsung Galaxy Spica I 5700

Comment: I think this might have something to do with kies. You have certainly to install it to have the drivers... I remember similar issue when I had the Samsung Galaxy S

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\LG Electronics\LG PC Suite\adb>adb install com.lge.filemanager-15052-v3.1.15052.apk
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
2683 KB/s (3159508 bytes in 1.150s)
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.lge.filemanager-15052-v3.1.15052.apk
Success

C:\Program Files (x86)\LG Electronics\LG PC Suite\adb>
```

We can use the adb.exe which is there in PC suit, it worked for me.
Thanks
Chethan

Answer (score -1):

1.question answer-In your mobile having Developer Option in settings and enable that one. after In android studio project source file in bin--> apk file .just copy the apk file and paste in mobile memory in ur pc.. after all finished .you click that apk file in your mobile is automatically installed.

2.question answer-Your mobile is Samsung are just add Samsung Kies software in your pc..its helps to android code run in your mobile ...