# Issues Deploying .apk to Phone

Tags: android, apk, adb

EDT: The root of my problem was making sure the drivers for the phone where installed. Left the post for documentation, in case anyone else has questions on how to verify if the adb can see their device or not.

I have a question related to: [how to install apk application from my pc to my mobile android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449707/how-to-install-apk-application-from-my-pc-to-my-mobile-android)

I'm using eclipse, and a Win7 VM (running through VMWare Workstation), which I use as my development machine.

I'm trying to get an .apk installed to my phone, so that I can do some testing with the real device. I have the phone setup to be in debug mode and have it so that when I connect via USB, that it connects the phone as a hard drive.

When I connect the phone, my phone connects to my VM, as I see the new drive, which I can access.

When I try `adb install c:\...\program.apk` I get:

```
error: device not found
- waiting for device -
```

Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

EDT:

Screenshots confirming the requested info:
[image]
[image]

EDT:

Looks like the issue can be as RStar pointed out... device manager doesn't identify the device properly:

[image]

Comment: Write "adb devices" in cmd and let tell me it shows your device or not ? it seems like your device is not connected

Comment: Check that you have driver installed for your device and Google USB Driver in Android SDK manager

Comment: @Rstart `adb devices` comes back with a blank list

Comment: @ArtemZinnatullin Confirmed `Google USB Driver` is installed

Comment: @VenomFangs i think your device is not connected , you need to install device driver , i think if i m not wrong your mobile drive is not present on my computer

Comment: @Rstar I posted a screenshot from eclipse showing the Google USB Driver being installed... do I need something specific for the phone, if so, how/where do I get it?

Comment: i think yes cause i have also installing my samsung , sony , htc device driver in my pc which helps to detect device

Comment: Your host OS is Ubuntu or another linux distro? Because I had to configure my OS using this [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) to let ADB recognize my phone.

Comment: @Rstar I think you are right. I just added another screenshot showing the issue in the device manager... thx!

Comment: @NahuelBarrios Its a Windows 7 VM, the info was included in the question.

Comment: @VenomFangs yes, that's why I asked about the host OS and not the VM. 
Maybe the VM recognize the drive but ADB needs something else to work.
In my case I was able to use the drive but ADB didn't recognize it as a connected device.

Comment: @VenomFangs yes dude you need to install device driver

Comment: @NahuelBarrios sorry, I see what you  mean, host is Win7 as well.

Comment: @Rstar I put an answer down giving some of the details I went through. If you want to spend the time to write up all the troubleshooting steps for the solution, I'll accept what you put as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So the root of the issue was the android device driver. In order to get the driver, for my HTC phone, I had to download the HTC Sync software from: http://www.htc.com/us/support/

After I got that and installed it, it installed the driver for me. I did note that when it installs that it changes the system path, which has its own adb.exe... If you try to do a `adb install` then you may get a message that the server is out of date. Some googling lead me to the fact of this extra `adb.exe`. I renamed the file and put the sdk path into my system path. After that I was able to do the `adb install` command without any issues.

@Rstar Thanks for the help!